# which unicode should be used UTF-8 and UTF-16 when deal with accented characters in java response to Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, unicode, encoding, utf-8

First of all, what is main difference between UTF-8 and UTF-16,

and when dealing with accented character in ajax to java, I facing an issue which

is in this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227083/java-response-to-ajax-with-accented-characters-garbled][1]

many thanks if you can help me with this.

Comment: if you have a choice, use utf-8, it's the de facto standard these days.

Comment: yeah, since UTF-8 support most of characters

Comment: all UTF- variants support all of the unicode characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading the [UTF-8 article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), it's excellent.

*>what is main difference between UTF-8 and UTF-16*

UTF-8 is variable width and can handle all the characters in unicode, The first 128 characters of UTF-8 is Latin-1 which is identical to 7-bit ASCII and therefore 7-bit ASCII is actually a proper subset of UTF-8 where every character is one byte this has the advantage that old character handling code will work seamlessly with your UTF-8 content if you know it's never going to be anything other than Latin-1.

For handling code pages outside of Latin-1 (your accented characters and other languages) UTF-8 will use more than one byte per character.

UTF-16 is a slightly older standard that can also handle all the unicode characters but doesn't have the backwards compatibility with ASCII because it's always at least double byte. Therefore UTF-8 is more efficient than UTF-16 for handling ASCII. (It's also more efficient for several other character sets, but it gets complicated.)

My advice is to always use UTF-8 unless you are forced to use UTF-16 by something like libraries. Most modern languages make converting between encodings fairly straight forward, so choose the one that will be most useful and most easy to support in the long run and my experience, particularly with Java has been that's UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question, but if you go to the linked question, even though I explicitly set chartset UTF-8 on both java and ajax, accented character still get garbled in ajax responseText, not sure how to fix it, can you please help with it.

Comment: Using character sets in HTML and HTTP gets complicated very quickly, you've probably forgotten to set the encoding at some point. Not only does the HTML need an encoding header, so does all the HTTP traffic.

Comment: I am sure I have set encoding header in response and request

Comment: Your server may not be correctly encoding the bytes but still setting the header. (I have actually seen this, the bug was an infinite loop that only happened when the server OS was Korean.)

Comment: It's hard to give specific advice without seeing the code. I suggest inspecting all the serialization code to ensure that all conversions of strings to byte buffers, and vice versa, are done with the right encoding. Similarly for reading and writing http responses.

Comment: ok, Thanks, can you please vote up this question, I need to 2 more reputation to vote up others answer